Register types for std::variant programatically
What am I trying to achieve

I want to write a lib that calls a method, with known form, on user defined types.
I want that method to accept as parameters, other user defined types.
Both categories of these types may have any number of additional methods and custom data members the user can dream up
I do not know the details of these types at the time I am writing the library
We will know the type definitions at compile time.
These types need to all be able to be contained by an std collection type such as vector or queue

Classic Inheritance - Attempt 1
In 1990, I'd be doing this with base classes the user derives from for state and event, have them put their custom data in the concrete classes, give me some typeid mechanism, register their types with my library using those typeids, and then do a dynamic cast for them when it came time to make the callbacks, but I want to avoid that.
My library would provide
class IEvent
{};

class IState 
{
public:
    virtual void enter(std::shared_ptr<IEvent> event) = 0;
    virtual void exit(std::shared_ptr<IEvent> event) = 0;
}

The user would define their concrete types in the application:
struct PedCrossingEvent : IEvent
{
    int m_customUserData;
};

struct TimerElapsedEvent : IEvent
{
    std::string m_othercustomUserData;
};

class GreenState : IState
{
public:
    virtual void enter(std::shared_ptr<IEvent> event)
    {
       // We'd need to perform the dreaded dynamic_cast to get to the concrete type in order to access the user's custom data.
    }

    virtual void exit(std::shared_ptr<IEvent> event)
    {
        // We'd need to perform the dreaded dynamic_cast to get to the concrete type in order to access the user's custom data.
    }
};

We'd have to have some enum somewhere, or similar typeid system, so the user would know what to cast to, given an interface.
Sure, I've heard "If you are using a dynamic_cast the design is wrong." Great! How do we do it right then? You cannot use virtual methods to overcome the problem of not knowing what data the user wants to include in their various concrete types. Unless maybe you want to use std::any or a void *. Is that they way to go? I dunno.
Visitor - Attempt 2
So, I did some Googling, came across CppCon talks on type erasure and the visitor pattern. "Hey maybe this solves my problems!"
Well, type erasure allows me to put any type in the same container, so it answers one requirement, but I still have to know concrete types to get at user defined data and casts have to occur somewhere when or before calling State::enter and State::exit.
Enter the visitor pattern.
Consider the following code listing and imagine I am writing a library that contains everything from the using Event line downward. While the types above that line are provided by the user of my library.
main here is just a minimal example of the types of things I'd be doing in library code rather than have the user do in application code.
I need to make the call to state::enter and give the user back their custom event type as a param.
I need to store the user's custom event types in a container.
I need to store the user's custom state types in a container.
Those types and their details are not known at the time I am writing the library. They are generic. They will be known, however, at compile time.
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

// User defined types examples
struct PedCrossingEvent{int m_myCustomUseData;};
struct ProgramTimeElapsedEvent{double m_myOtherUserCustomData;};
struct NoProgramEvent{std::string m_otherDataStill;};

class Elephant;

struct GreenState
{
    Elephant * m_customStateData;

    void enter(std::shared_ptr<PedCrossingEvent> predCrossingEvent)
    { 
        if (predCrossingEvent.m_myCustomUseData > 10) 
        {//...} 
    }

    void enter(std::shared_ptr<ProgramTimeElapsedEvent> programTimeElapsedEvent)
    {
       if( programTimeElapsedEvent.m_myOtherUserCustomData < 100.0 )
       {//...}
    }

    void enter(std::shared_ptr<NoProgramEvent> noProgramEvent)
    {
       if( noProgramEvent.m_otherDataStill< 100.0 )
       {//...}
    }

    void exit(std::shared_ptr<PedCrossingEvent> pedCrossingEvent)
    {}

    void exit(std::shared_ptr<ProgramTimeElapsedEvent> programTimeElapsedEvent)
    {}

    void exit(std::shared_ptr<NoProgramEvent> noProgramEvent)
    {}
};

// How do I, at compile time, register user defined types from above, that could be anything the user dreams up, with this variant in my library?
// I need some kind of "register type" compile time mechanism
using Event = std::variant<std::shared_ptr<PedCrossingEvent>,
                  std::shared_ptr<ProgramTimeElapsedEvent>,
                  std::shared_ptr<NoProgramEvent>>;

int main()
{
    std::vector<Event> events = { 
        std::make_shared<PedCrossingEvent>(),
        std::make_shared<ProgramTimeElapsedEvent>(),
        std::make_shared<NoProgramEvent>()
    };

    GreenState green;
    std::visit([&green](auto&& arg) { green.enter(arg); }, events[0]);

    return 0;
}

Demo
The problem here is the using statement would have to exist in my library and I don't know what types the user is going to make in the future. Even if that future is indeed compile time rather than runtime.
I am wondering if there exists some mechanism (perhaps template magic) for me to take some list of types supplied by the user, and register them, creating a std::variant using those types.
I am currently forming the question topic on this question.
Down the Rabbit Hole to Oblivion
I can try to wrap the using statement in a template type, but I feel like I only move the problem elsewhere. The user still has to tell me about types somehow. How can I make a method for them to register, without knowing the type parameters?
/*
* I needed a way to define the variant at compile time without knowing the user defined types
*/
template<typename... Types>
class RegisteredEventTypes
{
    // Helper to determine if a type is part of the variant
    template<typename T, typename VARIANT_T>
    struct isVariantMember;

    // Helper to determine if a type is part of the variant
    template<typename T, typename... ALL_T>
    struct isVariantMember<T, std::variant<ALL_T...>> : public std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, ALL_T>...> {};

public:
    using EventVariantType = std::variant<Types...>;

    static constexpr size_t getNumEventTypes()
    {
        return std::variant_size_v<EventVariantType>;
    }

    template<typename T>
    static constexpr bool isTypeRegistered()
    {
        return isVariantMember <T, EventVariantType>::value;
    }
};


int main()
{
    // Try out the template. The user will need to supply this to a registration method, but how can I make such a method without knowing the type parameters?
    using MyEventTypes = RegisteredEventTypes<std::shared_ptr<PedCrossingEvent>,
                                              std::shared_ptr<ProgramTimeElapsedEvent>,
                                              std::shared_ptr<NoProgramEvent>>;

    // Test that it works
    std::cout << MyEventTypes::getNumEventTypes() << std::endl;
    std::cout << MyEventTypes::isTypeRegistered<std::shared_ptr<NoProgramEvent>>() << std::endl;

    std::vector<MyEventTypes::EventVariantType> postedEvents = {
        std::make_shared<PedCrossingEvent>(),
        std::make_shared<ProgramTimeElapsedEvent>(),
        std::make_shared<NoProgramEvent>()
    };

    GreenState green;
    std::visit([&green](auto&& arg) { green.enter(arg); }, postedEvents[0]);

    return 0;
}

Summary
It is next to impossible for me to form the question topic without knowing the answer to the question. I can say this problem around this pattern comes up all the time in my career.
Classic, object-oriented polymorphism works great if you can cram all your problems into knowing exact method signatures beforehand and they won't ever change.
However, it breaks horribly when you don't know the data beforehand and new data along with new types can be added later. Even if that "later" is compile time. So what do I do?

std::variant is a compile time concept. You cannot "extend" it at runtime. So you will need to make a variadic class template of your own in which the user can specify the types. eg.

@PepijnKramer I don't want to extend it at runtime. I want to create the variant at compile time given a list of types supplied by the user of my library. Surely there is some template magic.

However I would not even consider using std::variant here. Allow your api to accept std::function's as callback registrations. Much more simple (no need to write visit methods), clients can call something like SomeRAIIRegistrationObject RegisterEvent(std::function<void(args...)>). And internally have a std::list<std::function<void(args...)> m_callbacks;which you can then "fire" usingm_callbacks(args...)` (where args... is not templated but a list of arguments you provide)

@PepijnKramer Registration of callbacks is left to me in my library and must be done a certain way, so as to follow certain rules, but I don't want to crawl down a design discussion for the library or its rules, as that will quickly lead far off topic. I want to focus on the concept of what to do when a user can supply any number of their own types. I need to be able to put those types in a collection and I need to be able to call methods of other user defined types (states) using the first collection of types they gave me as params (events) myself.

When I have to deal with more than a couple types, particularly when they are user-controlled/specified, I take the performance hit and store strings. With great versatility comes great reduction in optimization opportunities.

If you need observer pattern implementation, check boost.signals2; it's one of Doug Gregor's last contributions to C++, before turning his back and working on SWIFT.

This quickly evolves to the area of stateful metaprogramming (SMP). There are articles on SMP, but SMP is likely to be illegal in the standard. If you don't use SMP, the registration can only be one-shot, and they have to provide you with a collection (e.g. a tuple) of types at the same time anyway, which I'm not sure is what you are really interested in. Consider conceptually whether your registration can be described by a pure function at the type level. If not, standard template cannot achieve what you want and you are in the area of SMP.

Why not use regular polymorphism with virtual methods?

"I'm desperately trying to avoid [...] with dynamic casting [...]" Polymorphism (virtual) is meant to avoid any dynamic cast. If you have to, you're probably doing it wrong.

@Jarod42 because you cannot put user defined data in a base class. Both states and events could hold any manner of data that the user would want to get to when they are handling (called back) on a transition. In the provided listing, a dynamic cast would be required for the user to get at their custom data and I want to avoid that.

@Fareanor Yea, I've read that a thousand times and it isn't much use to me without knowing how to do it "right", hence this post on stack overflow. I don't see any alternative in this case. I am hoping someone will provide one in an answer,

@ChristopherPisz In that case, you should ask that question instead. The thing is, you don't need to access "user defined data" directly, but through an interface instead. Then every derived class should comply to that interface. No matter how they handle their data internally, they have to expose them through the given interface so that you don't care what the underlying object is. And tadaaaam, no dynamic_cast needed :)

@Faraenor interfaces are for methods, not for data members whose types and quantities are not known beforehand. I've edited the listing for you. The only way to get to a concrete type from an interface is through a dynamic cast and you absolutely would have to get to the concrete type to get at data members the user has defined on their type.

@RedWave I could be wrong, but I don't think what I am looking for here is observer pattern. I am controlling when callbacks are performed, so no need to the user to observe. What I need is the ability to make those callbacks using the user's custom types and on their custom types. In 1990, I'd be doing this with base classes the user derives from, have them put their custom data in the concrete classes, give me some typeid mechanism, register their types with my library using those typeids, and then do a dynamic cast for them when it came time to make the callbacks, but I want to avoid that.

Code that has a base pointer and wants to use derived data members sounds like an X-Y problem: there is often another way to arrange the code using the classes. If you truly do need object access, you can have virtual int get_int_data(Key) const; and maybe virtual void put_int_data(Key, int); where Key could be an index, string, etc. and so on for each needed type, but that gets ugly. Again, you should probably ask a question about these needs and alternatives.

@aschepler The thing about stackoverflow is it's damn near impossible to ask a simple question and leave it at that without people asking "well, why do you want to do that?" and then going down the rabbit hole the comment section here is going down. I'm happy to post more questions, but I feel like I'd just be repeating everything here in a different order.

You can templatize your Event on the types that participate in the event. template <typename... Members> using Event = std::variant<std::shared_ptr<Members>...>; This also makes it possible to have distinct clubs, each with different members. Event<Apple, Pear> and Event<Car, Truck>. Apple and Pear understand each other, Car and Truck understand each other, but Apple doesn't know what to do with a Truck.

Can Library code simply be template <typename EventList, typename StateList> class StateMachine;? From the above code, I only see user code...

"a dynamic cast would be required for the user to get at their custom data" Not really. Use double dispatch/visitor pattern and you will be all set.

@ChristopherPisz If you read well-received questions around here, you'll see that they're problems with strong motivations and they're described in clear succinct terms. If you ask a "simple question" that has obvious answers/alternatives without explaining why any of them are unacceptable, then of course everyone will ask you why they are unacceptable: something smells fishy. In this case, after you clarified what you want, we found out that inheritance and double dispatch seems to be the answer, which is not related to the original question at all.

@n.m.couldbeanAI can you show how with an example as an answer? I know what double dispatch is, I know what the visitor pattern is. I cannot visualize how they solve the problem at hand in code. In fact the question has an attempt at visitor in it with the point of failure exemplified.

@PasserBy doesn't anything that currently doesn't work smell fishy? I could of asked with the bottom paragraphs leading, but then only have to type out the tops ones with "tried that and here is why it didn't work." In the end, software engineering questions are complex and usually lead to lengthy discussion. I think it's inevitable.

Edited the original post yet again, but I feel like I am going to now get complaints akin to "This question is not focused enough" rather than "Well, why do you want to do that?" (too focused). I think the summary is well done enough it should convey the problem and question. I really hope.

No, the visitor your code has is of a different kind. You need a GoF visitor, which is a kind of double dispatch. Here is a simple version.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Unless I'm missing something, the double dispatch approach requires the base class State (provided in the library, I'm guessing) to know about every concrete event that could occur. This is not doable, because the library doesn't know which user-supplied events might exist.

It sounds like Jonathon Coe's polymorphic_type proposal for "incomplete types" could be a good fit for this.
I've been to a few of his talks which have progressively made more sense over time.
See https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p0201r6.html for the proposal.
Also see https://github.com/jbcoe/polymorphic_value/blob/main/talks/2022_08_02_cxx_london.md for the latest talk
Repo is at https://github.com/jbcoe/polymorphic_value/tree/main
There is a recording of his talk at CppOnSea22 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjLRX4WMvlU
the talk at C++ London was clearer.

@Wutz You are right, I forgot to show what the library itself should do. It needs to be templatized by the state type. It is also possible for the user to supply a compoment that does a single static cast. I will fix the example if I find time.

Here is fixed code using only static_cast (in the machine framework, not in user code) which is guaranteed to be correct if the machine is set up exactly once with one user state type.

I think a solution will become more apparent when you start thinking concretely about what you want your public interface to look like.
For example, say you intend your library to be used something like this:
struct foo_event {};
struct bar_event {};
struct {
    // ... enter and exit methods
} state;

int main() {
    // Using variadic parameters to pass the events:
    statelib::apply_events_variadic(state, foo_event{}, bar_event{});
    // Using a tuple to pass the events:
    statelib::apply_events_tuple(state, {foo_event{}, bar_event{}});
}

If this syntax is acceptable, then you don't actually need variant or type erasure - you can just deduce the available event types based on what the user passes to you. You did explicitly say that you need them to be containable in an std container. While tuple technically meets that brief, I'm still going to guess this is not sufficient.
If you do need runtime lists of type-erased events, then maybe something like this could work:
struct foo_event {};
struct bar_event {};
struct {
    // ... enter and exit methods
} state;

int main() {
    statelib::Context<foo_event, bar_event> context{state};

    // taking events as a vector of variant<foo_event, bar_event>
    context.apply_events({foo_event{}, bar_event{}});

    // if you need, you can give the user a way to extend the list of possible events:
    auto extended_context = context.extend<baz_event>(); // returns Context<foo_event, bar_event, baz_event>
}

It is obviously just an iteration on your RegisteredEventTypes idea. But this approach gates the interface to your library behind supplying a list of possible events. I'm not sure I understood what your qualm was with this general approach, but maybe this solves the issue you had with it?

From the user's perspective, the interface to my lib would look like registerEventTypes(...),  registerStates(...), registerTransitions(fromState, toState, event, guards, actions), and then they'd simply call stateMachine.queue(make_shared()); when an event occurs and let the lib call their state's enter and exit methods, passing the event as a param, following the rules of UML state charts.

I'm gonna give another go at trying to work through some manner of register methods with template params and see where I get.

@ChristopherPisz Does this suit your needs: https://godbolt.org/z/b71cT4TeY ? The idea is to skip registering states and events, just register transitions and the library deduces the available states and events from that.
